# Multitrack audio recording for Windows 7

Tags: gratis, windows-7, audio-recording

- Should work for Windows 7
- Allows simultaneous recording of inputs (e.g. USB microphone and mic via jack)
- Recordings should be kept separate, i.e. not merged to one track
- Should export .WAV files separately
- Should be free or provide the functionality in the free "lite" version

---

**Audacity** only allows recording one track without special hardware.

**Krystal Audio Engine** seems to be dead and the last version seems to be not running on my machine.

Other options seem to get expensive really fast, but I do not need a full-fledged DAW!

---

**My intent**: Comparing the measurements of two microphones to each other, which means that I record the same sounds. I do the processing in MATLAB.